# Devise Sign up with Ajax in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I am using devise for my rails app, and i want sign up to be processed through Ajax.Currently i am following up this [tutorial](http://natashatherobot.com/devise-sign-up-ajax-rails/)  .So far the user registration works (user data get inserted to the database through Ajax ), but the user is not being automatically signed in after registration. How do i accomplish this?There is  [this tutorial](http://natashatherobot.com/devise-rails-sign-in/) which shows Ajax sign in steps ,but i am not sure if i need it,if yes how? Here is my code

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
 class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

 def create
 build_resource

 if resource.save
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    return render :json => {:success => true}
  else
    set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if   is_navigational_format?
    expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
    return render :json => {:success => true}
  end
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  return render :json => {:success => false}
end

end

# Signs in a user on sign up. You can overwrite this method in your own
# RegistrationsController.
def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
sign_in(resource_name, resource)
end
end
```

**Routes**

```
   devise_for :users 
   devise_for :users , :controllers => {registrations: 'registrations'}
```

**Helper**

```
   module MyappHelper
def resource_name
     :user
    end

    def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
    end

    def devise_mapping
     @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
    end
    end
```

**Form**

```
     <%= form_for(resource,:as=>resource_name,:url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
     <%= devise_error_messages! %>
     <%= f.label :Username %>
     <%= f.text_field :username %></p>
     <%= f.label :email %>
     <%= f.text_field :email %>
     <%= f.label :password %>
     <%= f.password_field :password %>
     <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
     <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
     <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
     <% end %>
```